# Find frequency of each column in data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame as below, and i would like to find the frequency for each column.

data.frame ;

```
No      Location     Age         Size         Gender
1        Trinidad     25          3              1
2        Asin         33          2              2
3        Trinidad     33          5              2
4        Trinidad     23          3              1
5        Asin         25          5              1
6        Asin         23          2              2
7        Trinidad     23          4              2
```

Desired output

```
Location    Loc_Freq  
Trinidad       4
Asin           3  

Age   Age_Freq     
23       3
25       2
33       2

Size    Size_Freq  
2          2
3          2
4          1
5          2   

Gender    Gender_Freq
 1            3
 2            4
```

Can anyone help? Thank you ahead.

Comment: Use `aggregate` with `length`, or just `table`

Comment: Can you give me a sample on how to do it? I try table, but never get it right :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table`:

```
> t <- read.table(text="No      Location     Age         Size         Gender
+ 1        Trinidad     25          3              1
+ 2        Asin         33          2              2
+ 3        Trinidad     33          5              2
+ 4        Trinidad     23          3              1
+ 5        Asin         25          5              1
+ 6        Asin         23          2              2
+ 7        Trinidad     23          4              2",head=T)
> table(t$Location)

    Asin Trinidad 
       3        4 
> table(t$Age)

23 25 33 
 3  2  2 
> table(t$Size)

2 3 4 5 
2 2 1 2 
> table(t$Gender)

1 2 
3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your looking for `lapply` and `table`

```
> lapply(df[, -1], function(x) as.data.frame(table(x)))
$Location
         x Freq
1     Asin    3
2 Trinidad    4

$Age
   x Freq
1 23    3
2 25    2
3 33    2

$Size
  x Freq
1 2    2
2 3    2
3 4    1
4 5    2

$Gender
  x Freq
1 1    3
2 2    4
```